# Are light clients connected to a particular full node and stay connected to it throughout?

Tags: light-client

Wondering if this is how the architecture works.

For instance if that full node stops running does that mean the light client also stops running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works exactly the same way as full nodes. When two full nodes are connected to each other, and one disconnects, the other simply connects to a different full node instead. Same for a light client.